# What is happening that the cursor is moved back to line 1 when my first line starts with a number?

Tags: buffers

Once in a while, I have a file which somehow forces the cursor to line 1 when I switch back to it with <kbd>Ctrl-^</kbd>.

So, I load 2 or more files, and one of the file starts with the following:

```
   1. blah
   2. foo
   3. bar
 ...
 199. zoo
```

While in that file, I move to some line, such as 44.

Now I want to go to one of the other files I loaded and thus hit <kbd>Ctrl-^</kbd>, which works just fine, I do some edits...

Finally, I'm ready to come back to that file shown above, the one where the cursor was on line 44. So I hit <kbd>Ctrl-^</kbd> and... it switches to the file, but the cursor is moved to line 1 every time.

Editing the first line and removing the spaces, i.e. `1. blah` instead of   `1. blah`, prevents that behavior. What option/feature is being hit in this situation? Can it be turned off?

Comment: Try `:set hidden` or try `:h last-position-jump`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Hmmm... The "hidden" works, but then it lets me switch between buffers without having to save which is probably going to cause trouble... although an `:ls` shows you what's saved and what isn't. Would the "last-position-jump" work across any number of buffers? The code looks like it would only work between two buffers.

Comment: @Alexis imho 'hidden' is a must, files can be written when leaving. `:h autowrite` `:h bufleave`.

Comment: Just to add to this, there's a fairly broad consensus that to get the most out of Vim you should set `'hidden'`. (Personally, I'd state it in even stronger terms: `'nohidden'` is awful. :)